Angular - Custom form validator
I have two mandatory form controls as: minimumCharacters and maximumCharacters. I want to show an error, if the given maximumCharacters is smaller than the given minimumCharacters.
Here is how I have defined my form:
this.form.addControl('minimumCharacters', this.formBuilder.control(1, [Validators.required]),{ emitEvent: false });

this.form.addControl('maximumCharacters', this.formBuilder.control('', [maximumCharactersValidator(1)]), { emitEvent: false});

And here is my maximumCharactersValidator:
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn} from '@angular/forms';


export function maximumCharactersValidator(minValue: number): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
        console.log("control.value: ", control.value);
        let maxValue = control.value;
        if (maxValue > minValue) {
            return { maximumCharactersValid: true}
        }
        else {
            return { maximumCharactersValid: false}
        }
        return null;
    }
}

But this way I don't have access to the control value!

You can work with control.parent to get the parent form group and get the control with name: "minValue"
If the validation is true, you should return { maximumCharactersValid: null } to represent no error. Returning { maximumCharactersValid: true } mean the validation failed.
export function maximumCharactersValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    let minValue = (control.parent as FormGroup)?.get("minimumCharacters")!.value;

    let maxValue = control.value;
    if (maxValue > minValue) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return { maximumCharactersValid: true };
    }
  }
}

When you add the validator, you don't need to provide the argument.
this.form.addControl('maximumCharacters', 
  this.formBuilder.control('', [maximumCharactersValidator()]), { emitEvent: false});

Demo @ StackBlitz

NOTE: when is valid you should return null NOT {maximumCharactersValid:null} Else the formControl becomes invalid always. (write {{form.controls['maximumCharacters'].valid}} in your .html

Thanks @yong-shun it is working how I want.

Thanks @Eliseo, yes I'm caring of minValue,  I just didn't add it to the question to keep it clean.

@Eliseo btw the link you've provided is not correct, can you please provide the right one?

Remember that you need take account also when you change the "minimumCharacter". I love the solution in this SO -And I love quote mySelf :)

@user6781 ::glups:: sorry, just corrected the link

For this kind of situation you generally add FormGroup validator, not FormControl.
export const isInvalidValue = (value: string | undefined | number): boolean => {
  return value === undefined || value === null || value === '';
};

export const minMaxValidator: ValidatorFn = (
  form: AbstractControl
): ValidationErrors | null => {
  const min = form.get('minimumCharacters')!.value;
  const max = form.get('maximumCharacters')!.value;

  if (isInvalidValue(min) || isInvalidValue(max)) {
    return null;
  }

  return Number(min) > Number(max) ? { invalidMinMax: true } : null;
};

form = inject(FormBuilder).group(
  {
    minimumCharacters: [1, Validators.required],
    maximumCharacters: [1, Validators.required],
  },
  { validators: minMaxValidator }
);

StackBlitz example
